# Is there any explanation why $ or jQuery is not working in chrome extension development?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have downloaded the `jquery compressed, production jQuery 3.5.1 slim build` file in project root directory, and added in manifest file, then tried to run jQuery functions using `$` sign, I tried to do it in content script and background script, but I got error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

[image]

manifest.json

```
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage","https://*/"],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js","jquery.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/get_started16.png",
      "32": "images/get_started32.png",
      "48": "images/get_started48.png",
      "128": "images/get_started128.png"
    }
  },

  "icons": {
    "16": "images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "images/get_started128.png"
  },

  "content_scripts":[{
      "matches" : ["https://www.amazon.com/s?*"],
      "js" : ["content.js","jquery.js"]
  }],

  "manifest_version": 2


}
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({productLink: 'test', search_url: url.href }, function(response) {
    console.log(`message from background: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
});

function isProductUrl(url){
    let arr = url.split('/');
    if(arr[4] == 'dp')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


$.ajax({
  url: "www.localhost.com/search",
  context: document.body
    }).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

Comment: Swap the order: put `jquery.js` first in manifest.json.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you so much. you just saved my life!

Comment: If you are using the slim build, I would be surprised if the `ajax` method is included.